# File Transfer job using windows protocol fails on Workload Scheduler

Tags: windows, protocols, workload-scheduler

On a dynamic agent, I'm running a File Transfer job using Windows protocol.
The file transfer to my Windows system always fails.
The job goes in ABEND and the following error is reported

```
AWKFTE007E An unexpected error has occurred. The following error was 
returned: ""CTGRI0011E An error occurred when accessing the remote 
registry or service control manager." target machine.
```

Do I miss any setting in the job definition, on TWS or on the target machine?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not due to a wrong job definition or a missing configuration
on TWS side.
It is necessary to verify these three things on the Windows target system:

- verify that the user can login to the remote Windows machine (make sure that user and password in the job definition are correct)
- verify that Remote Registry service is started on the Windows system (Open the Administrative Tools Control Panel, Open Services and make sure that the Remote Registry service is running)
- LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry key is set to 1. Open the Registry Editor and navigate to 
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System. 
  Make sure that the key LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy exists, otherwise cretae it as New Dword, and set its value to 1.

After these steps I've rerun the File Transfer job and it completed successfully. Windows system reboot was not required in my case.